# Which one of the following represents a deadlockfree order of invoking the P operations by the processes?

Tags: process, operating-system, deadlock, semaphore

Three concurrent processes X, Y, and Z execute three different code segments that access and update certain shared variables. Process X executes the P operation (i.e., wait) on semaphores a, b and c; process Y executes the P operation on semaphores b, c and d; process Z executes the P operation on semaphores c, d, and a before entering the respective code segments. After completing the execution of its code segment, each process invokes the V operation (i.e., signal) on its three semaphores. All semaphores are binary semaphores initialized to one.
Which one of the following represents a deadlockfree order of invoking the P operations by the processes?
(A) X:P(a)P(b)P(c) ,  Y:P(b)P(c)P(d)   ,  Z:P(c)P(d)P(a)
(B) X:P(b)P(a)P(c) ,  Y:P(b)P(c)P(d)   ,  Z:P(a)P(c)P(d)
(C) X:P(b)P(a)P(c) ,  Y:P(c)P(b)P(d)   ,  Z:P(a)P(c)P(d)
(D) X:P(a)P(b)P(c) ,  Y:P(c)P(b)P(d)   ,  Z:P(c)P(d)P(a)

Can anyone please provide some explaination for the answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is (B) as this is the only one where all processes open the locks in the same order.

In `(A)` `X` does `P(a)` then `P(c)` and `Z` does `P(c)` then `P(a)` so `X` could have `a` and be waiting for `c` and `Z` could have `c` and be waiting for `a`

In `(B)`, `P(a)` is before `P(c)` in `X` and `Z`, `P(b)` is before `P(c)` in `X` and `Y` and `P(c)` is before `P(d)` in `Y` and `Z`

In `(C)`, `P(b)` and `P(c)` are the problem in `X` and `Y`

In `(D)`, `P(a)` and `P(c)` are the problem in `X` and `Z` and `P(b)` and `P(c)` in `X` and `Y`

I worked on a system the had this sort of problem with file locking.  The solution was to ensure all processes opened the files in the same order, so we choose to open them in alphabetical order.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Ans is (B).
But I did not understand your last line... Can you please explain why the order should be alphabetic ? Because here, ans (B) has not alphabetic order.

Comment: The order doesn't have to alphabetic, it was just the convention we used.  You can use any order as long as all processes use the same order (answer edited).